# gauge.js -> Need modification on javascript to PercentageColors function

Tags: javascript, gauge, donut-chart

I found this amazing javascript gauge meter: http://bernii.github.io/gauge.js/

There's an option to make it looks like a gauge

```
new Gauge(target).setOptions(opts)
```

Or like a Donut (the one I need)

```
new Donut(target).setOptions(opts)
```

In the "gauge mode" there's an option **percentColors** that change the gauge color when it change its value. But this parameter doesn't work on "donut mode".

I tried to change the *gauge.js* but with no success... any javascript wizard could help me on this one?

The *gauge.js* file is in the link, and my code to "call it" is here:

```
var opts = {
angle: 0.46, 
lineWidth: 0.1, 
radiusScale: 1, 
pointer: {
   length: 0.6, 
   strokeWidth: 0.035, 
   color: '#000000'  
},
limitMax: false,     
limitMin: false,
percentColors: [[0.0, "#ff0000" ], [0.50, "#f9c802"], [1.0, "#a9d70b"]],
strokeColor: '#EEEEEE',  
generateGradient: true,
highDpiSupport: true,    
};

var target = document.getElementById('graph'); 
//var gauge = new Gauge(target).setOptions(opts); 
var gauge = new Donut(target).setOptions(opts); 
gauge.maxValue = 3000; 
gauge.setMinValue(0);  
gauge.animationSpeed = 32; 
gauge.set(3000); 
gauge.setTextField(document.getElementById('gauge-value'));
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found myself a simpler solution, instead of using the parentColor function on the Donut mode, I used some ifs/elses to limit the numbers and set the color in that specific location:

```
 if (value<=20)
 { 
  opts.colorStart='#291B00';
  opts.colorStop='#FF0000'; 
 }else if (value>20 && value <=60)
 { 
  opts.colorStart='#290000';
  opts.colorStop='#FF7E0D'; 
 }
 else if (value>60)
 { 
  opts.colorStart='#002903';
  opts.colorStop='#00FF00'; 
 }
```